# Count and positions of an element in a given list

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request

I want to implement an operation on the following list:

For a given arbitrary length of list $\{a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,\cdots\}$, the task is to find the number of zeros and their position(s).
So I want my output to be:

> {number of zeros, {position(s) of zero(s)}

For example, $\{0,1,2,-1,0,1,3,0\}$, I want to count $0$; so zero happens twice and the position of zero to be in 1st, 5th, 8th position, i.e., I want my output as $\{3, \{1, 5 ,8\}\}$.

First of all, I know how to count the zeros:

```
  list1={0,1,2,-1,0,1,3,0};
  Count[list1, x_ /; x == 0]
```

Then it gives `3` as an output. Maybe I can find the position(s) by using the loop explicitly, but I think there is a simpler way to implement it in Mathematica.

Comment: `{Length@#, Flatten@#} &@Position[list1 = {0, 1, 2, -1, 0, 1, 3, 0}, 0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For integer lists:

```
{Length @ #, #} & @  Random`Private`PositionsOf[list1, 0]
```

> ```
> {3, {1, 5, 8}}
> ```

This is much faster than alternatives for long lists with relatively few zeros.

Answer (score 8):

```
zeros[ll_] := {Length[#], #} &@Flatten@Position[ll, 0]
```

or

```
zeros[ll_] := {Count[ll, 0], Flatten@Position[ll, 0]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**Using `PositionIndex`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
list1 = {0, 1, 2, -1, 0, 1, 3, 0};

cpi[k_List, 
  el_] := {Count[#, el], 
    If[MissingQ@PositionIndex[#][el], {}, PositionIndex[#][el]]} &@k

cpi[list1, #] & /@ Range[0, 4]
```

---

Other variations:

```
Through[{Count[0], Flatten@*Position[0]}[list1]]

{Length@#, #} &@PositionIndex[list1][0]
```

---

> {{3, {1, 5, 8}}, {2, {2, 6}}, {1, {3}}, {1, {7}}, {0, {}}}